# Run apitooling analysis from command line

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, p2

I want to run the following script from apitooling:

```
<target name="analysis">
        <echo>Starting apitooling.analysis ...</echo>
        <apitooling.analysis baseline="${baseline}" profile="${profile}" report="${report_folder}\analysis\reportXml" debug="${debug}" />
        <apitooling.analysis_reportconversion xmlfiles="${report_folder}\analysis\reportXml" htmlfiles="${report_folder}\analysis\reportHtml" debug="${debug}" />
        <echo>Finishing apitooling.analysis ...</echo>
    </target>
```

The problem that it needs the ant to run with the same JRE of eclipse, this could be easy to do in the eclipse enviroment from the "External tools" menu, the problem is when I want to run this from command line, because I got the following error message:

> Problem: failed to create task or type apitooling.analysis Cause: The
>   name is undefined. Action: Check the spelling. Action: Check that any
>   custom tasks/types have been declared. Action: Check that any
>   / declarations have taken place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Eclipse `antRunner` task to run Ant within the Eclipse environment. See http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2FantRunner.htm (note the versions of plugins mentioned in this article will vary between Eclipse releases).

Comment: Great; thanks for the quick and helpful answer, I will update you with the result after trying it.

Comment: I would like to thank you again for your answer, it worked perfect :)

Comment: You can 'accept' the answer by clicking the tick mark - see http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer